# Change an another version SQL Server on the Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I have on my PC 2 versions of SQL Server (2016, 2019). Now by default, there is the 2016 version. How can I change this to 2019?

Comment: What do you mean - default? When opening SMSS you have to specify which server you want to connect to.

Comment: If by default you mean the default instance, you can't. The instance name is determined at the time of installation and cannot be changed once installed. To change the default instance you can either do an in-place upgrade for the current one from 2016 to 2019 or remove it and install a new default instance.

Comment: [Upgrade SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking about Database Instances [Engines] (e.g. `MyServer\TestInstance`): you have to upgrade the 2016 engine to 2019 and uninstall 2019 instances and install 2016.

**Don't forget to backup data and server configurations before any action**

If you are asking about SQL Server Management Studio [SSMS]: Just uninstall unwanted studio.

Comment: *"If you are asking about Database Instances [Engines] (e.g. `MyServer\TestInstance`): you have to uninstall both instances and install it again."* this is simply not true. YOu can upgrade instance of SQL Server; you cannot upgrade SSMS.

Comment: @Larnu; Yeap, SQL Server Engine is upgradable.

Comment: So why tell the OP they must uninstall it? That could be disastrous if they have production data.